# Having Trouble Downloading Tidyverse in R

Tags: r, linux, tidyverse

Hi I am New and having a bit of trouble downloading the tidyverse packages

Here is what I am working with :
R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
Linux system
I cant seem to get it to download on my desktop but was able to get it on the cloud version of R.
I think Im missing something but have no idea what it could be.
I have tried removing it but still nothing.
If anyone can explain what I am doing wrong and how I can correct it,  it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!
Commands Used to download R:

```
echo "deb http://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian buster-cran40/" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/r.list
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys FCAE2A0E115C3D8A
sudo apt update
sudo apt install r-base libnss3
get https://download1.rstudio.org/desktop/bionic/amd64/rstudio-1.4.1106-amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i rstudio-1.4.1106-amd64.deb
sudo apt -f install
```

Here is the last bit of the Error

```
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘curl’
* removing ‘/home/barobbie/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/curl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘curl’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘openssl’ ...
** package ‘openssl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
Using PKG_CFLAGS=
--------------------------- [ANTICONF] --------------------------------
Configuration failed because openssl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: openssl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libssl_dev (Solaris)
 * brew: openssl@1.1 (Mac OSX)
If openssl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a openssl.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
-------------------------- [ERROR MESSAGE] ---------------------------
tools/version.c:1:10: fatal error: openssl/opensslv.h: No such file or directory
 #include <openssl/opensslv.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
---------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘openssl’
* removing ‘/home/barobbie/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-
```

library/4.1/openssl’
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘openssl’ had non-zero exit status

- installing *source* package ‘xml2’ ...
  ** package ‘xml2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  ** using staged installation
  Package libxml-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
  Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libxml-2.0.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable No package 'libxml-2.0' found Package libxml-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path. Perhaps you should add the directory containing` libxml-2.0.pc'
  to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
  No package 'libxml-2.0' found
  Using PKG_CFLAGS=
  Using PKG_LIBS=-lxml2
  ------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
  Configuration failed because libxml-2.0 was not found. Try installing:
- deb: libxml2-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
- rpm: libxml2-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
- csw: libxml2_dev (Solaris)
  If libxml-2.0 is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
  PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libxml-2.0.pc file. If pkg-config
  is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
  R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'

---

ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘xml2’

- removing ‘/home/barobbie/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/xml2’
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘xml2’ had non-zero exit status
  ERROR: dependency ‘openssl’ is not available for package ‘ids’
- removing ‘/home/barobbie/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/ids’
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ids’ had non-zero exit status
  ERROR: dependencies ‘curl’, ‘openssl’ are not available for package ‘httr’
- removing ‘/home/barobbie/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/httr’
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘httr’ had non-zero exit status
  ERROR: dependency ‘httr’ is not available for package ‘gargle’
- removing ‘/home/barobbie/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/gargle’
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘gargle’ had non-zero exit status
  ERROR: dependencies ‘httr’, ‘xml2’ are not available for package ‘rvest’
- removing ‘/home/barobbie/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/rvest’
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rvest’ had non-zero exit status
  ERROR: dependencies ‘gargle’, ‘httr’ are not available for package ‘googledrive’
- removing ‘/home/barobbie/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/googledrive’
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘googledrive’ had non-zero exit status
  ERROR: dependencies ‘curl’, ‘gargle’, ‘googledrive’, ‘httr’, ‘ids’ are not available for package ‘googlesheets4’
- removing ‘/home/barobbie/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/googlesheets4’
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘googlesheets4’ had non-zero exit status
  ERROR: dependencies ‘googledrive’, ‘googlesheets4’, ‘httr’, ‘rvest’, ‘xml2’ are not available for package ‘tidyverse’
- removing ‘/home/barobbie/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/tidyverse’
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
‘/tmp/Rtmp4NJJ8T/downloaded_packages’

Comment: The actual error message will be before that last bit; there should be something earlier explaining (possibly not very helpfully) what is wrong. Can you post more of the output when you try to install tidyverse?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: To clarify, In downloading the tidyverse packages to my desktop version of R studio. I was met with a error that I didn't receive when I did the same exact thing on the Cloud version of R studio. This is my very first time using R so I am trying to learn as I go. Please bear with me. I have edited the text and added additional error to the post. Thanks In advance! @Community

Answer (score 2):

I figured out what I was missing. Typically the Errors will give you a hint as to what is needed to fix the issue  so I just corrected the missing issue with in my terminal as per the following.

```
sudo apt install libcurl4-openssl-dev
sudo apt install libssl-dev
sudo apt install libxml2-dev
```

Then in R

```
install.packages ("tidyverse")
```

This allowed me to install tidy verse on R with in a Linux system